# Issue with Apple Mail after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: mail.app, macos

My boss upgraded his MacBook to OS X El Capitan, and after doing so, Apple Mail started downloading again all mail messages from the server. As he has around 130K mails stored on the server, this makes the computer crash.

Why did AppleMail forgot all about mails already downloaded when upgrading the OS? How can we fix this? We already tried unabling all accounts and enabling them one by one, but there are 130K mails in one single account, so this was no help.

Comment: IMAP or Exchange?

Comment: You can limit the download to the last 6months in settings to get him up and running. This can be set in the preferences for that account.

Comment: What specifically happens when "makes the computer crash"? Do you have a good backup from right before the upgrade?